# How to change language of months in "SelectDateWidget" django

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using widget SelectDateWidget, and i am  trying to change the name of months form english to portuguese, i already tried this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

is not working

forms.py

```
class RegisterForm2(forms.Form):
gender = forms.ChoiceField(label="Género", choices = UserRegister.gender_choices, required=True)
birthdate = forms.DateField(widget = forms.SelectDateWidget, localize=True)
class meta:
    model = UserRegister
    fields = ['gender',
              'birthdate']
```

Comment: do you use language switch option? I mean switch between language

Comment: the trick is change the value of variable LANGUAGE_CODE to 'pt' in file settings.py, i did that before but didn't work... but now is working...

Comment: Add answer. This helps other developer too.

Comment: It is done... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way to do it, in the settings.py file change the value of variable LANGUAGE_CODE to 'pt'... i tried this before and i don't now why didn't work, and now is working... well...